# Hit AWS ECS load balancer endpoint using java

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to hit a load balancer endpoint using AWS SDK for java, however I dont see any API for in the AmazonECSClient class. I see the option to set endpoint, region, credentials etc.

```
AmazonECSClient.builder()
  .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
  .withRegion(region)
  .withEndPoint()
  .build();
```

The endpoint is tested using curl command and it works - `curl http://elb-dummy-endpoint.us-east-1.elb.domain.com:80/invocations -d '{"query": "some query"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Do I have to do a regular API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to hit a load balancer endpoint using AWS SDK for java

You would not use the AWS SDK for hitting a load balancer endpoint. The AWS SDK is for interacting with the AWS API for doing things like creating a load balancer. The load balancer is serving your API, not the AWS API, so you would not use the AWS SDK to interact with the load balancer.

The `AmazonECSClient` class you are trying to use is for doing things like creating/updating/deleting ECS clusters, services and tasks. It is not a client for the application you have running on ECS.

> The endpoint is tested using curl command and it works - curl
> http://elb-dummy-endpoint.us-east-1.elb.domain.com:80/invocations -d
> '{"query": "some query"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

You are testing it here with `curl` to make basic HTTP calls, you are not using the AWS CLI tool. In Java you would do the same thing, [make a basic HTTP call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) against the endpoint.